# ArgumentNullException was Unhandled -- Help

Tags: vb.net

This code is throwing an ArgumentNullException at the specified line below and I don't know why.

```
Private Sub ShaftLoad()
        Dim newShaft As New Shaft
        Dim shaftlist As New List(Of Shaft)
        shaftlist = DBShaft.GetShaftList
        Dim shaftArray(shaftlist.Count) As String


        For i As Integer = 0 To shaftlist.Count - 1
            shaftArray(i) = (shaftlist(i).ShaftName)
        Next

        ShaftComboBox.Items.AddRange(shaftArray) 'Exception is thrown here.

End Sub
```

Comment: @John, yes he does.  `Dim shaftArray(shaftlist.Count) As String` is equialent to `string[] shaftArray = new string[shaftlist.Count + 1];`

Comment: @John, it was in the [initial version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9a2a05ca-40b5-497a-b2f0-ab09a90278ec/view-source), just formatted poorly.

Comment: @Matt: Oh, sorry, it was so bad that I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Dim shaftArray(shaftlist.Count) As String
```

That's a quirk of VB.NET, an array declaration states the *last valid index* in the array, not the number of elements in the array.  Your array is thus one element too large.  That will bomb in the AddRange() call, it adds a string that is Nothing.  Fix:

```
   Dim shaftArray(shaftlist.Count - 1) As String
```

Or bypassing the explicit array entirely using Linq:

```
    Dim shaftlist = DBShaft.GetShaftList()
    ShaftComboBox.Items.AddRange(shaftList.Cast(Of Object).ToArray())
```

Comment: Awesome! I seriously was just thinking that since Hallie said above that one of my items in the array might be Null but I couldn't figure out how to fix it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx)

> ArgumentNullException -  An item in the items parameter was null.

Maybe you could do something like this..

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To shaftlist.Count - 1
            shaftArray(i) = Iif(shaftlist(i).ShaftName=Nothing, String.Empty, shaftlist(i).ShaftName)
 Next
```

Comment: How does that help him?  We can all Google the method.

Comment: I'm not really sure about your business logic (if your shaftlist(i).ShaftName should contain null values), but I gave you an idea what to check.

Answer (score 0):

`shaftArray(shaftList.Count)` is null.  Your array are 0-indexed, with the maximum index `shaftlist.Count`.  But you never set that max element.  You probably want:

```
Dim shaftArray(shaftlist.Count - 1) As String
```

Comment: I can't set ShaftArray(shaftList.count) = nothing                    so how do I not make it null then?

Comment: @Matt, you don't need to change your assignments.  Rather, you just want a one smaller array.